# Different results by different methods of counting

Tags: r

I have a data.frame df2 and I wanted to find the number of rows where 'var' is > 140. I used following methods and they gave me different results.

```
> morevar = df2$var > 140
> describe(morevar)
morevar 
      n missing  unique 
   8388      58       2 

FALSE (8352, 100%), TRUE (36, 0%)
```

(36 by this method)

```
> another = ifelse(df2$var > 140,1,0)
> table(another)
another
   0    1 
8352   36
```

(36 by this method)

```
> df3 = df2[var>140,]
> str(df3)
'data.frame':   94 obs. of  44 variables:
```

(94 by this method)

The count is 36 from excel sheet (by sorting and direct counting)

Please help.

Comment: Can you please provide us with sample data? It's hard to tell without knowing the classes of variables, and the presence of `NA`s.

Comment: Did you `attach` df2? otherwise i don't see how your third method would work. It is supposed to be `df3 <- df2[df2$var>140,]`.

Comment: The NAs were creating the discrepancy. With na.omit(.. it works all right. Thanks. How is df3=df... different from df3<-df... ?

Comment: I did not attach df3. I only saw that 94 observations have been selected and I presumed they all had var>140.

Answer (score 1):

58 (missing) + 36 = 94

From `help("[")`:

> **NAs in indexing**
>
> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an
>   unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a
>   logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a
>   list. (It returns 00 for a raw result.)

So, use `length(na.omit(df3$var))`.

Comment: Yes. The missing values were being included in method 3. With function na.omit(df3$var) gives 36 entries. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow code:

```
x <- na.omit (df2)
nrow(subset(x, x$var>140)
```